# Deeplink does not work on Android 9 (Beta)

Tags: branch.io

I have Branch io setup and it works perfectly fine on all other android versions except android 9 beta. It does not open anything, neither browser nor the app. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I tested this on an emulator and deep linking was working as expected. In the meantime, I am looking to test this on a physical device as well.

Could you please submit a ticket to integrations@branch.io and attach a video recording of what you are experiencing?